# jQuery (or CSS3) Switch between content sections on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I hope you can point me in a right direction.

I would like to replicate navigation, that is similar to one on this website:
http://vsamarehorosho.ru/

Basically, the idea is that you don't allow user to have different sections of the website to be on a screen at the same time.
So, if the section is larger than a screen it scrolls until you reach the bottom of the section. If you scroll further, you jump onto the next section.

If section is smaller than a screen size, you will see the main section at the top and part of the next section down the bottom, but when you try to scroll, next section jumps to the top and the one after it shows down the bottom only if this one is smaller than a screen size.

On the example, all slides are 100% height, but that's not always achievable.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use jQuery scroll function to check if the user is scrolling and use scrollTop to position the page to your next section.

Comment: I am trying that at the moment. I haven't figured out yet, how to pass all section IDs that must be scrollable.

Comment: Just go for [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). Make things easier :)

Answer (score 0):

wrap all sections in a div with height of 100%;

this way, 
if section is under 100% height, the wrapper will help ensure that only one sections shows on page.
if section height is over 100%, the scrolling can occur on the wrapper, rather than on the page.

Comment: Well thank you, but that won't do, cause you still can scroll to a point when you see bottom half of the first div and top half of the second. And this is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a fixed height in pixels. Determine the requisite height of your 'tallest' div and set all divs to that height. This may leave some whitespace on some divs, but will insure that only one div is visible at a time.

You can then use one of many 'scroll to' scripts available online and create navigation links to each individual section. Ariel Flesler's scrollto.js is an excellent example. http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

M.J.
5150 Design

Answer (score -1):

I made a library that can make it possible. (fullpage.js)

It even works with smaller sections.